# Onde encontro para download/instalação na Eclipse IDE, o pacote WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, gui, window-builder

Preciso criar aplicações com interface gráfica em Java. Utilizo o Eclipse Mars como IDE para programar em Java, notei que ele não dispõe na sua instalação padrão o pacote WindowBuilder para se fazer telas gráficas em programação, como o NetBeans IDE que possui a opção Form JFrame que contém varias ferramentas para se fazer botões, caixas de textos, menus, etc.

Onde posso encontrar uma forma de trabalhar com interface gráfica sem ter que mudar de IDE, usando apenas o Eclipse para programar? Há alguma opção nativa do Eclipse que faz o que preciso que não localizei? Se tiver podem me ajudar a encontra-lá? Ou qual link para baixar um pacote que contém essas ferramentas (creio que seja o WindowBuilder)? Obrigado.

Comment: Você está usando o "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" ou "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Eclipse SDK for Java SE.

Comment: Ao baixar o "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" 64 bits nesse link: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ ele já vem com o WindowBuilder instalado. Não foi esse que você baixou?

Comment: Não era esse que estava utilizando mas, acabei de baixar aqui. Onde encontro a opção similar ao "Form JFrame" do NetBeans, nessa versão?

Comment: Veja se a minha resposta abaixo responde a sua pergunta. Não sei de onde você havia baixado o Eclipse antes, mas baixando do link que eu passei já tem o WB por padrão.

Comment: Obrigado Math sua ajuda foi bastante significativa. Consegui o que procurava. Valeu!

Comment: Se a minha resposta lhe ajudou a resolver o problema considere aceitá-la, conforme mostra esse link: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117). Aproveite e faça um [tour] para conhecer um pouco mais o funcionamento do nosso site. E bem vindo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A versão Mars do Eclipse já vem com o WindowBuilder instalado, portanto, basta baixar o pacote destinado ao JavaSE no site do próprio Eclipse, no link: http://eclipse.org/downloads

Escolha o pacote de nome "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers", que é a versão que lhe interessa.

Será baixado um `.zip`, não é necessário instalar, apenas o descompacte em uma pasta de sua escolha e rode o `eclipse.exe´.

Crie um novo projeto, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida crie o JFrame no ícone do lado, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Caso alguém esteja na mesma situação que me deparei, pode simplesmente baixar uma outra versão do Eclipse, como a "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" que já possui esse pacote instalado ou ainda Ir em Help > Install New Software > Work with e adicionar esse link "http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.5/" e baixar apenas o pacote WindowBuilder, sem a necessidade de trocar de versão Eclipse.

Grato a todos que me ajudaram.

Answer (score 0):

Basta ires ao seguinte link e seguires os passos.

https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Comment: Quando eu clico no "here" que é um link na frase "Instructions and system requirements for installing WindowBuilder can be found **here**." ele me leva para o endereço http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/installation/index.html que se refere à versão do Kepler. Será que essas instruções servem para o Mars?

Comment: Sim são as mesmas.